# setting up figure handle for basemap

Tags: python, handle, figure, matplotlib-basemap

I don't really understand how to use properly figure handles, for example in setting up a figure and clearing and/or closing it.  Here, I am plotting using basemap in a for loop.

I fixed the overlapping problem of my colorbars appearing in my plots produced by the for loop, by adding the lines `fig=plt.figure()` and `plt.clf()` but I do not understand why or how I can use the 'fig' handle below in my script (is it the same as the 'cs' handle for the m.pcolor?)

I also get an error message that there are too many open figures when I have the below code in the for loop, and so added the line `plt.close(fig)`

```
fig=plt.figure()
cs = m.pcolor(LON_subset,LAT_subset,ma.masked_where(land_mask_subset,data))

# add colorbar
cbar = m.colorbar(cs,location='bottom', pad="3%")
cbar.set_label('J/m$^2$',size=17)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=16)

plt.clf()
plt.close(fig)
#plt.show()
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: It is working, I just feel like I am not using the figure handles properly -- What is the difference between the 'fig' handle and the 'cs' handle, and is there a way to close the figure and clear the figure with the 'cs' handle?

Comment: `cs` is the handle to the drawn image itself.  This is useful if, for example, you want to get the colormap or data range associated with the drawing.  If you use subplots, you could have multiple plots within a single figure; the handles like `cs` would give you access to each individual plot, while the figure handle `fig` would still refer to the entire "page" or "window" the plots were drawn in.

Comment: In particular, when you create `cbar`, it is using the data range and colormap assigned to `cs` in order to determine how the colorbar should be drawn.

Comment: thanks, that answers my question . i dont know if i can accept a comment but i upvoted them